# Loop to search page for unknown element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Java test automation and trying to write a simple for statement that will find the existence of a particular account number that identifies the element that is present.

My problem is that I can't get the loop to go through more than once. It seems that it breaks out of the loop right away when the condition is false.

I have exhausted the search. Any pointers or example. Appreciate it folks.

Here is the complete `cssSelector` format for my element I am trying to loop through:

```
   #edit_account_**1201** > div.row.delete-mode.hideout > div.col-md-4 > 
   div.btn.btn-danger.btn-sm
```

Simply, what I would like to achieve since I know the range of the `edit_account` numbers and the format is to loop through the range, lets say 1200 -1250. And Once the `element/cssSelector` if visible and present I break our of the loop. :-)

```
     for(int i =1200; i<1250; i++){     
        System.out.println("Checking through now");
        if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#edit_account_"+i+DELETE_CONFIRMATION_BUTTON)).isDisplayed()){
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#edit_account_"+i+DELETE_CONFIRMATION_BUTTON)).click();
            System.out.println("Account number deleted is:" + i);   
            break;
           }
        }
```

Comment: you should put break as ELSE part.

Comment: What u r trying to acheive? Can we have a problem statement? Ur loop will break as soon as it finds the element, since you have put `break` in `if` condition.

Comment: Hi Vivek, just edited the problem description. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Are all the elements in the range of 1200-1250 account numbers visible or is it just at certain moment only one number in the range is?

Comment: Just one number in that range. And I don't know which one.

Comment: Can you please add the HTML snippet of the element ? If you can provide  the snippet of its parent element, that will be helpful too. Thanks.

Comment: Can u provide html? Also can you provide output of the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you are getting an exception when you try to locate the initial element.  Do you see an exception? If so, can you provide the stack trace?

Consider grabbing all the elements you need first with:

```
  List<WebDriver> elements =  driver.FindElements(By....whatever your locator is...)
```

And, then iterating through the list with a loop and running your assertions or conditional logic.

Comment: Problem is that I have a long list of unique elements. Listing them would take me a while. Any other work around? Thanks

Comment: I understand, but if you try to find a WebElement with a locator doesn't exist, you're going to get a "NoSuchElementException" and the code will cease to run.So when you try #edit_account_1200... and there's no match, your code will stop. What @Shamik  and I are suggesting is to use .findElements because it won't throw that exception.

Comment: Or, if this page just has an astonishly large number of elements that would meet your cssSelector, you could try to use @contains and an XPath locator to limit the items in the list :  

"//a[contains(@class,'#edit_account_12')]"  

to get just the links (for example) that contain the 1200-1299 accounts.  In your code, you'd build this path programmatically using the first two digits of the account you're looking for, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two solution :

1. Try using driver.FindElements which will not throw an exception or
2. Try to catch the exception and continue back to the beginning of the loop after that.

   loop{

   ```
   try{
     if(){
      driver.findelement....
     }
    }
   catch(){

   }
   ```

   }